# when does an embedding induce an isomorphism of Chow rings?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $Y$ is a subvariety of $X$, and both are nonsingular.  I'm interested in knowing a nice condition to make the inclusion $i\colon Y\to X$ induce an isomorphism of Chow rings $A^{.}(X)\cong A^{.}(Y)$.  For example, if $X$ and $Y$ were spaces and I wanted an isomorphism in cohomology, I might hope to show that $Y$ is a deformation retract of $X$.

So my novice question (not very precise, sorry) is if intersection theory offers an analogous or at least comparably useful technique.  I'd appreciate a pointer to an example, say, in Fulton's book.  (Which, if I'd read and understood fully, of course, surely I could answer my own question!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hi Graham,

I can't think of too many interesting situations where this happens, 
but here is one. If $i:Y\to X$
is the inclusion of the zero section of an algebraic vector bundle, then restriction gives an isomorphism of  Chow groups $CH^*(X)\cong CH^*(Y)$ (indexed by codimension). A proof can be found in [Fulton, chap 1, prop 1.9]. This fits with your intuition because Chow groups are
$\mathbb{A}^1$ homotopy invariants ($CH^*(X\times \mathbb{A}^1)\cong CH^*(X)$), and 
$Y$ would be a deformation retract of $X$ in this sense.

Comment: Thanks, Donu.  That's exactly the sort of thing I was hoping for!